# ember properties and javascript chaining

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Looking at the ember.js documentation (http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) I understand how to use properties, but hadn't run across chained methods in an object declaration before.

It looks to me like the `property` method should get called immediately, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    var firstName = this.get('firstName');
    var lastName = this.get('lastName');

   return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

var tom = Person.create({
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Dale"
});

tom.get('fullName') // "Tom Dale"
```

If I make a small js snippet, nothing here seems to do anything.  http://jsfiddle.net/xXStr/

```
var a = {
    what: function() {
        alert ("oh yeah");
    },
    bar: function() {
        alert ("bar");
        return this;
    }.what()
}
a.bar();
```

How do chained methods in an object declaration work?

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside the [Ember source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/ext/function.js), you will find that the `Function` prototype is extended to include a `property` method.

```
Function.prototype.property = function() {
  var ret = Ember.computed(this);
  return ret.property.apply(ret, arguments);
};
```

[Looking deeper](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/packages/ember-metal/lib/computed.js), we see that `Ember.computed` returns an instance of `Ember.Computed`.

```
Ember.computed = function(func) {
  var args;

  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    args = a_slice.call(arguments, 0, -1);
    func = a_slice.call(arguments, -1)[0];
  }

  var cp = new ComputedProperty(func);

  if (args) {
    cp.property.apply(cp, args);
  }

  return cp;
};

// ...

function ComputedProperty(func, opts) {
  this.func = func;
  this._cacheable = (opts && opts.cacheable !== undefined) ? opts.cacheable : true;
  this._dependentKeys = opts && opts.dependentKeys;
}

Ember.ComputedProperty = ComputedProperty;
```

Thus, whenever you write

```
foo: function() {
  return this.get('bar')
}.property('bar')
```

you are actually creating an anonymous function and then immediately invoking its `property` method, returning an instance of `Ember.ComputedProperty`. This is what gets assigned to the `foo` property.